# Print divisors of a number in C

Tags: c

In my program I am not getting correct output if `n = 6` then I get output: `1 2 3 6 7`

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d", printdivisors(n));
    return 0;
}

void printdivisors(int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @alk Question is to print divisors of number

Comment: This `printf("%d",printdivisors(n));` does not make sense. What do you expect do be printed here?

Comment: Welcome (again) to the Mysterious World of Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect:

```
printf("%d",printdivisors(n));
```

It should just be:

```
printdivisors(n);
```

**Note that if you had enabled compiler warnings you would have received at least 3 warnings about this and other problems with your code. For gcc you need to add `-Wall` to your command line. Always compile with warnings enabled and always take notice of any warnings.**